# StreamReader not working correctly after reloading scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamreader

I have a stream reader I am using to parse data into a program. When I first open the scene from the main menu, the stream reader works correctly in parsing the data (I omitted the parse in my snippet as the code is long). The text.text output to the screen on the first run is G. If I go load back to the main menu, and then back into this scene however the text.text output is the first line of the text document where my code reads text.text = line and I am trying to figure out why. Is sr.Close() not the proper way to close the stream reader? Or is the file somehow still open?

```
void Start () {
    text.text = "A";
    trimAndPlaceDataSets = GetComponent<TrimAndPlaceDataSets> ();
    text.text = "B";
    string AthenaData = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Athena.txt";
    text.text = "C";
    PopulateAthenaData(AthenaData);
}

void PopulateAthenaData(string s){
    text.text = "D";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s)) {
        text.text = "E";
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        text.text = line;
        while (line != null) {
            //Do Stuf
            sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Close();
        text.text = "G";
    }
}
```

And this is how I am loading my scenes

```
public void LoadPressed() {
        scenesDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        loadButton.SetActive(false);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scenesArray[scenesDropdown.value]);
    }
```

Comment: Consider using a "`using`" statement with classes such as `StreamReader` that implement `IDisposable`.  When the `StreamReader` drops out of scope it will be closed and disposed of automatically, simplifying your logic, especially when considering exception handling.

Comment: How exactly are you loading back into these scenes? Are you using LoadScene() while running the game?

Comment: I am using SceneManager.LoadScene(string) from the main menu. Added the code in an edit.

Comment: Please don't include notes like "thanks in advanced[sic]" in questions. See [no thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is about "Garbage Collection" (visit this Url : "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/")
Simple answer is C# can release (dispose) lots of things after you using them but somethings like "files" aren't one of them. You have to release them after using and if you don't that, your file will be open and another process can't access that. You need to dispose "StreamReader" after your work is done. And "using" do that (you don't need to write a custom disposer for that).

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Your file path")) 
     {
         //do your work
     }
```

after that, file will be released automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Using do close stream for you in proper way, this is because StreamReader class has implemented interface IDisposable, and this lets to use using statement which after scope end automatically calls Dispose method in SreamReader and in that method are cleared resources and closed opened files and if needed as last step is called garbage collector

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
{
    //do stuff with stream reader
    //sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: looks like infinite loop, because in you snippet you never assign line to null, missing: line = sr.ReadLine();

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and the one above? You had to add a new answer 15 minutes later even when this has been solved. Nothing is improved too...

Comment: only difference that I answered earlier and OP used my solution, but accepted answer is more detailed

Comment: Oh yes, I just realized you answered first. Sorry about that. Please don't just post code in your future answers. Explain it otherwise your answer might be downvoted +1.